# SSO with Kerberos in Apache - No users names in logs?

Tags: apache, apache2, single-sign-on, kerberos

I'm using **apache with kerberos** and Drupal SSO/LDAP, which works fine.

In my logs, however, I don't see the users that are authenticated, only:

```
kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos 
Acquiring creds for HTTP/drupalsite@EXAMPLE.COM 
Verifying client data using KRB5 GSS-API with our SPNEGO lib 
Client didn't delegate us their credential
GSS-API token of length 185 bytes will be sent back 
AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : granted 
AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
```

Shouldn't this show at the end the username that has been granted access, like the below?

```
kerb_authenticate_a_name_to_local_name einstein@EXAMPLE.COM -> einstein
```

as per https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/ig_ldap_sso_auth/SSO/Pitfalls.html

**UPDATE**
I added `KrbLocalUserMapping on` which strips the domain from usernames

and in a test php `$user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];` shows it returns "joeblock" instead of joeblock@example.com while also in my apache logs now appears at the end with

```
kerb_authenticate_a_name_to_local_name joeblock@EXAMPLE.COM -> joeblock
```

**but** for my drupal site it still doesn't hence I'm wondering if this might be to do with how the drupal SSO/LDAP implements this? Does it need to be set to return this information?

Comment: Wild guess: maybe Drupal assumes that principal `joeblock@EXAMPLE.COM` should map to a Linux local user `joeblock` as it's the way SSSD would map it with default rules. So maybe it actually checks whether user `joeblock` actually exists to retrieve its groups i.e. authorization. That's how Hadoop works, anyway.

Comment: sorry I pasted the wrong code I added, it's `KrbLocalUserMapping on`, at first it stripped the domain now for some reason doesn't anymore. 

I think you might be right because I'm using the LDAP plugin with SSO setup, my suspicion is since it the windows username get's passed on and is found in LDAP ith authenticates as expected and mus somehow not pass the username back in order to see them in apache error logging?!?